# Error compiling x264 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, x264

I'm trying to compile and install the [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) H.264/AVC encoder.
I've got `gcc` installed. But I get the 'No working C compiler found' error when I run:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
```

What can I do?

The config log said:

```
/bin/gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -falign-loops=16 -mdynamic-no-pic -o conftest
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-loops=16' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
```

Comment: Did you try `gcc` at the command-line to see if your gcc is available, e.g., in your path?

Comment: Yes, it's available. It's in /usr/bin/gcc.

Comment: The config.log said : checking for -mdynamic-no-pic... no
  2 Failed commandline was:
  3 --------------------------------------------------
  4 /usr/bin/gcc conftest.c -Qunused-arguments -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -falign-lo    ops=16 -mdynamic-no-pic   -o conftest
  5 clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-loops=16' [-Wunused-command-line-ar    gument-hard-error-in-future]
  6 clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) i    n the future

Comment: Run: `/usr/bin/gcc --version`; the chances are that it is `clang` in disguise.  I get: `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`.  I tend to use GCC 4.8.2, but I built that for myself.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact version, Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) that i have. Thanks a lot Jonathan Leffler, I'll follow your link to build GNU GCC.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error and found a simple solution here:
http://www.xin.at/x264/x264-guide-macosx-en.htm

Before actually being able to start the build we will however need to remove a GCC compiler flag from the configure script, that the newer LLVM+CLANG compiler will not be able to handle. For that, please open the file configure in your favorite text editor and look for the following spot:

darwin*)
  SYS="MACOSX"
  CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -falign-loops=16"

Replace that with the following, effectively removing the -falign-loops=16 option:

darwin*)
  SYS="MACOSX"
  CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"

After doing the above, libx264 builds just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The `configure` script is trying to set a compiler option `-falign-loops=16` that the `clang` compiler (masquerading as `gcc`) declines to accept.

Either get (compile) your own real GCC and use that (I've done the [compilation and installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173518/install-gnu-gcc-on-mac/21213759#21213759); it's not very hard, though neither is it trivial), or work out how to stop the `configure` script from failing simply because it assumes that the `-falign-loops=16` option must be supported by all versions of GCC.  That is the sort of thing the `configure` script should be checking so that you don't run into that sort of failure.  Ultimately, this is a bug in the configuration for this code.