# How do I make sure that my default C/C++ compiler is GCC

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, riak

I'm trying to install Riak from source on macOS (https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/setup/installing/mac-osx.1.html#installing-from-source).

There is a note:

> Riak will not compile with Clang. Please make sure that your default
>   C/C++ compiler is GCC

How do I find out which compiler is the default and how to change it?

macOS Catalina (10.15.4), *which* command prints:

```
$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: I'd assume the make file is clever enough to pick the right compiler if it's installed. In any case why not just try and see if it works?

Comment: Please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between GCC and Clang/LLVM using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On macOS Catalina (and prior versions, and most likely subsequent versions too), there are two aspects to the problem and some suggested solutions.

#### What is the name of the compiler used by `make` by default?

```
$ mkdir junk
$ cd junk
$ > x.cpp
$ > y.c
$ make x y
c++     x.cpp   -o x
cc     y.c   -o y
$ cd ..
$ rm -fr junk
```

This shows that the names used by `make` are `cc` and `c++`.  Those are not obviously `clang` or `clang++`, but neither are they obviously `gcc` and `g++`.

```
$ which cc c++
/usr/bin/cc
/usr/bin/c++
$
```

#### Which compiler is it really?

Which compiler really lives behind the names `cc`, `c++`, `gcc`, `g++`, `clang`, and `clang++`?  We can check which compiler these really are by getting them to identify their version:

```
$ for compiler in cc c++ gcc g++ clang clang++
> do
>     which $compiler
>     $compiler --version
> done
/usr/bin/cc
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/usr/bin/c++
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/usr/bin/gcc
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/usr/bin/g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/usr/bin/clang
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/usr/bin/clang++
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
$
```

As you can see, the versions installed in `/usr/bin` are all the same compiler, and that compiler is `clang` or `clang++`.

This was run on a machine with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and XCode 11.3.1.  The latest version of XCode — 11.4.1 — is only available on Catalina.  However, the general conclusion is the same — all the C and C++ compilers are really `clang` and `clang++` in disguise.

#### How do you get GNU GCC onto your machine?

How do you get a real GNU GCC — a real GCC, not `clang` in disguise — onto your machine?

- Use [Brew](https://brew.sh/) to install GCC (I've not checked which version of GCC is current).
- Or use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (again, I've not checked which version of GCC is current).
- If you're adventuresome, do it yourself (but I've not yet succeeded at building GCC 9.3.0 on Catalina; I have a GCC 9.2.0 built on macOS Mojave 10.14.x that works OK on Catalina though — with one environment variable needed to locate the headers).
- Maybe [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) — it lists GCC 8.4 as being made available in 2020; I don't know about newer versions.

Be aware that Apple has taken to hiding the system header files miles out of the way (not in `/usr/include` —  and you can't modify that part of the file system to add a symlink to where they've hidden them):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

(You mean you couldn't guess that?  Me neither!)

#### How do you change the default compiler?

Once you have GCC installed somewhere appropriate, you need to ensure you use the 'real' GCC and not the 'fake' in `/usr/bin`.  You do that in part by ensuring that the bin directory for the 'real' GCC occurs on your PATH before `/usr/bin`.  I have GCC 9.3.0 installed under `/opt/gcc/v9.3.0`, so `/opt/gcc/v9.3.0/bin` appears on my PATH long before `/usr/bin` does.

You also need to ensure that the configuration for `riak` (the software you're installing) uses the correct compilers.  If there's a `./configure` script, run it with the correct path specified for the compilers.  For example, I might use:

```
./configure CC=/opt/gcc/v9.3.0/bin/gcc CXX=/opt/gcc/v9.3.0/bin/g++
```

You can also set these values as environment variables.

If it uses `cmake` or some other configuration package, you'll need to consult the installation instructions.  That's usually `README` or sometimes `INSTALL`.

---

See also (increasingly older posts):

- [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrade to Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58278260/151168)
- [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530212/15168)
- [Install GNU GCC on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213759/15168)

Comment: This answer helped a lot to clear up the confusion.  

In case you are not sure whether you already have `gcc` installed or where it is, you can `brew info gcc`. It was in `/opt` for me as for the answerer. Configure further as he suggested in __How do you change the default compiler?__ above.

Comment: Also, if the "veritable `gcc` path before `/usr/bin`" method didn't work for you you can relink. See this further: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450861/460688

Answer (score 2):

For *macOs* follow below steps:

**Method-1**

1. Install **gcc** compiler using **homebrew**. (install *homebrew* if you haven't already)

   ```
    brew install gcc
   ```
2. Suppose brew installs gcc-12 version on your system, check using:

   ```
     gcc-12 --version
   ```
3. Open terminal and use the following command:

   ```
      cd /opt/homebrew/bin
   ```
4. Below given command will make a symbolic link for g++ with g++-12. Using this, you can easily switch between different versions

   ```
      ln -s gcc-12 gcc
   ```

Now check `gcc --version`, it will be changed from macOs default clang to gcc.

**Method-2 (Creating aliases)**

1. Open Terminal and open either ***.zprofile*** or ***.zshrc*** file

   ```
   open .zprofile
   ```
2. After opening the file add below lines, save and close it.

   ```
   alias gcc="gcc-13"
   alias g++="g++-13"
   ```
3. Restart terminal, and it will work fine with using just **gcc** or **g++**

**NOTE:** you can do same steps for changing g++ also, just replace `gcc-12` with `g++-12`

**EDIT:** Also maybe at the time you'll see this answer brew installs latest **gcc** or **g++** version like **gcc-13** etc, so make sure to modify commands accordingly.

- **5 May 2023:** Now, by default brew installs the latest **gcc-13** version, so use above commands accordingly.